# How to delete autogenerated columns from Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: .net, telerik, radgrid

I dynamically change columns for a RadGrid, for some data sources I need AutoGenerateColumns for other I don't. But after data binding with AutoGenerateColumns=True I tried to clear Columns list and add new, but old autogenerated columns still there. There is an example on VB.NET of code for adding new column

```
reportGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = False
reportGrid.Columns.Clear()
Dim column As New GridBoundColumn
column .DataField = "field1"
column .HeaderText = "header1"
reportGrid.Columns.Add(column)
```

`Columns.Clear()` doesn't remove autogenerated columns, how can I remove them?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[link to telerik website](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/gridview-prevent-column-autogenerate.html)

this is the documentation on how to do what you are trying to do.

or check  `Grid.MasterTableView.AutoGeneratedColums` collection.

Comment: That's WPF. Though the question doesn't specify what platform.

Answer (score 1):

According to telerik it is not possible to delete a Grid column which is already added in the Grid's Column collection. One suggestion will be to set its Visibile/Display property to false.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-removing-column-on-runtime.aspx

Comment: according to telerik itsself, there is a remove function.  http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/radgridview-adding-removing-columns.aspx

Comment: @Pabloker thank you, it is not appropriate for me to use Visibile/Display property because I can bind lot of different data sources on the page and some of them are autogenerated, maybe it worth to use different RadGrid for those tables.

Comment: @gashach Thank you also, but in the article that you gave describes removing non-autogenerated columns only.